# why doesn't recursive grep appear to work?

Tags: grep

The man page for `grep` says:

```
-r, --recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively
```

OK, then how is this possible:

```
# grep -r BUILD_AP24_TRUE apache
# grep BUILD_AP24_TRUE apache/Makefile.in
@BUILD_AP24_TRUE@mod_shib_24_la_DEPENDENCIES = $(am__DEPENDENCIES_1) \
(...)
```

Comment: What is the output of `command -v grep`?

Comment: @John1024 the output of the command you are asking, is `/bin/grep` so it is not an alias of some kind

Comment: Try `grep -R BUILD_AP24_TRUE apache` and tell us what happens.

Comment: @John1024 yes, this is embarrasing, I did not check if `Makefile.in` is a symlink... because, this file is not a symlink.  Except, in this case, it is. I want 5 minutes alone with the person who made this a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two likely causes this type of problem:

1. `grep` is aliased to something that excluded the files you were interested in.
2. The file of interest is in a symlinked directory or is itself a symlink.

In your case, it appears to be the second cause.  One solution is to use `grep -R` in place of `grep -r`.  From `man grep`:

```
   -r, --recursive
          Read  all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic
          links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file
          operand is given, grep searches the working directory.
          This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory, recursively.
          Follow all symbolic links, unlike -r.
```

Comment: I found that `grep -r xyz` *does*  include symbolic links for me (Default `grep` from Ubuntu/Mint). The man page is unclear to me: What are symbolic links that `are on the command line`? Doesn't make any sense to me. @John1024 Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Suppose `/spool` is a (regular) directory and `/spool/run` is a symbolic link.  `grep -r xyz /spool` will search for `xyz` under directory `/spool` but will not include `/spool/run` in the search because `/spool/run` is a symbolic link and it is not on the command line.  By contrast, `grep -r xyz /spool/run` will search for `xyz` under `/spool/run` because, even though a symlink, it is listed on the command line.

Comment: Thanks. Probably just me but a better wording to me would be "only if they are passed as arguments" or something. Anyway: It still includes symlinks for me, even if I do not pass the name of the symlinked directory. I also checked if `grep` is aliased. It only has `grep='grep --color=auto'`. I do have the same man page as in your answer, though. Not sure what's going on but I'm not unhappy about it. Just wondering.